# Selecting some row numbers from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server management studio 2008 and use `TOP` to select some data from DB.

```
SELECT 
    TOP 3 Name, Company, ta_Content, Email, Writedate
FROM dbo.ta_CONTACT
WHERE Name in ('David', 'Filo', 'Rain', 'Cone', 'Source', 'Tailor', 'Fier', 'Venesse')
ORDER BY Writedate;
```

So by using `TOP 3`, I can collect top 3 data from 8 given data. But What I want to do is selecting 5-7th data from the given 8 data.

I may use `ROW_NUMBER()` but I want to use `TOP` logic by using `NOT IN`. But I'm not sure where to put `NOT IN` logic to show 5-7th data only.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Tim answer is the way to go. But if that doesnt answer your question  you should provide a more detail example. Because you say didnt want/know use `ROW_NUMBER`. Try writting your schema in [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I'm using 2008 version of the SQL and thanks for the Sql Fiddle recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Writedate ASC) AS rownumber,
    Name, Company, ta_Content, Email, Writedate
    FROM dbo.ta_CONTACT
) AS t
WHERE rownumber >= 5 AND rownumber <= 7
```

Comment: what does order by key ASC part mean?

Comment: No I don't have an index column

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.It is not right way.

```
select TOP 2 Name, Company, ta_Content, Email, Writedate from (
SELECT TOP 3 Name, Company, ta_Content, Email, Writedate FROM dbo.ta_CONTACT
WHERE Name in ('David', 'Filo', 'Rain', 'Cone', 'Source', 'Tailor', 'Fier', 'Venesse')
ORDER BY Writedate desc)a ORDER BY Writedate
```

Answer (score 0):

Using TOP (3) and filter out the row 1 - 4, then you can get 5 - 7 records

```
SELECT TOP (3) 
    * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Writedate) Seq, 
        Name, Company, ta_Content, Email, Writedate
    FROM dbo.ta_CONTACT
    WHERE 
        -- The search criteria must be inside the inner select statement
        Name in 
        ('David', 'Filo', 'Rain', 'Cone', 'Source', 'Tailor', 'Fier', 'Venesse')
) filtered
WHERE 
    Seq >= 5 
    -- If you do not need the TOP statement just use below condition
    -- Seq BETWEEN 5 AND 7
```